# undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk' with MinGW on Linux

Tags: c, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I made a small program on Linux that looks like this:

```c
#include <dirent.h>

int main(){
    DIR* assetsDir = opendir("someDir");
    closedir(assetsDir);
}
```

On Linux (Nobara, which is based on Fedora) everything works just fine. The code compiles (GCC) and runs as intended. On Windows (MinGW) as well. But with x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc for cross compilation on Linux the following error occurs:

MinGW on Nobara with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc src/main.c`

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingwex.a(lib64_libmingwex_a-dirent.o):(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `__strcpy_chk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does MinGW on Linux lack this function? My `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --version`:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20221121 (Fedora MinGW 12.2.1-6.fc37)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I looks like the problem was actually caused by something completely different than what I initially thought. Let me just update the question real quick

Comment: Please include the command line used to build your program.

Comment: @BrechtSanders It's just the simple `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc src/main.c` Adding `-lmingw32` doesn't change anything

Comment: Try playing with flags like `-fstack-protector` and `-lssp`, as this may be related to the stack protector.

Comment: Thank you @BrechtSanders! That worked. I just had to add one of those.

Comment: Which one exactly?

Comment: Doesn't matter which one